# Using a Bootstrap theme with Django

Tags: python, django

I have an Admin theme from Themeforest and I wanted to create it's backend with Python using the Django framework. However when I copy the theme files into the template folder the CSS does not load. The structure is this:
Mysite/myapp/templates/myapp/...here is where the index.html is and a folder for CSS, JS and Images. The href in the html is

Anyone knows how to load the css, JS and images so that it doesn't give me plain text when I start the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to creat static folder and place all your CSS and JS folders and files. And refer that correct static files in template.

Index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" >
```

Comment: Already done that. I think my issue is coming from settings.py where I set the Static url and dir

Comment: Can you include the relevant settings ?

Answer (score 0):

If you set static `STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static"),]`  Then Create directory in project root directory called static & placss css js there

Your directory structure should be

```
project_name
  > static
     > js
        > your js files
     > css 
       > your css files
```

Also check the django docs for [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) serving static file in development(runserver) environment

In case of static files is in Templates directory

`STATICFILES_DIR = [
  os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static"),
  os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "Templates/<app_name>/"),
]`

Comment: What if I have a folder in project root directory called Templates, in that folder I have a folder 'appname', then in the 'appname', I have the CSS folder. How do I set the static_files_dir?

Comment: Simple! add directory in `STATIC_FILES_DIRS`. updated in answer

Comment: Thanks, solved it. All I needed was to edit the paths in the settings.py. I had put STATIC_URL= (app_name/static) instead of simply (static)